# Checking Broadcast Receiver Permission Programatic

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

I have a Broadcast Receiver for my C2DM(old) Messaging like

```
    <receiver android:name=".C2DMRegistrationReceiver">
           <!-- Receive the actual message -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="com.test" />
          </intent-filter>
          <!-- Receive the registration id -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="com.test" />
          </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="REGISTRY_RETRY" />
              <category android:name="com.test" />
          </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

for security reasons you should declare a permission for this receiver like

```
<receiver android:name=".C2DMRegistrationReceiver" permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
```

my problem here is that my 3. Intent Filter dont receive the call because i enforce the com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND Permission.

So my Question: Is there a way to define 2 Permissions for one Broadcast Receiver or can i enforce the Permission for the Caller inside my onReceive Code?

i tried

```
  private boolean checkC2DMPermission(Context context) {
    String permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND";
    context.enforceCallingPermission(permission, "Keine C2DM Permission");
    return true;
  }
```

also i've tested   `context.checkCallingPermission(permission)` its -1 for a C2DM Register Intent. Enforce gave me a SecurityException.

Comment: Why not simply move the logic you are using for `REGISTRY_RETRY` into a separate `BroadcastReceiver`? Use inheritance or composition if there is common code that you want to have between this one and the C2DM one.

Comment: Yeah thats the simplest solution for sure. I'm just curious and a bit stubborn over that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I ran into the same problem, and this comes up in a google search, so here we go.

The short answer is you can't.

The mentioned [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission(java.lang.String)) are intended for when you are executing an IPC, for example a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) using AIDL.

The broadcast receiver is not executing an IPC, so you can't get the senders permissions, from the broadcast receiver.

To enforce the permission, you have to declare the permissions for the broadcast receiver in the manifest. This works because Android enforces the required permissions before it is delivered to the receiver.

The permissions are common for all actions in the receiver. To handle this, you can split the broadcast receiver into separate classes, as @CommonsWare proposes.